# Xamarin Android Player

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-android-player

I'm just getting into trying out some Android development with Xamarin, and while going through the documentation about installing Xamarin for windows, I come finally to this page

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/android-player/

in which I am to setup the high performance android emulator.

I have followed all the steps, but when i try to run it, I get a dialog telling me

```
A Xamarin.Android subscription is required to use this beta.
```

Do I understand correctly that this player is not usable with the 'Starter' plans?

Assuming the above is true, can I assume my only recourse until I arrive at a point which I am ready to pay the subscription fee (or start the trial), is to use the standard google provided emulators?

Thanks

Comment: You can also use http://www.genymotion.com/ emulators with Xamarin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, the "Starter" plan does not have any "subscription" attached to it, so yes, you will have to be at least "Indie" to use the Android player, at least while its still "in preview", quote:

"The Xamarin Android Player is currently in preview. During the preview period it is only available to users with a valid Xamarin subscription."

from: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/android-player/

Comment: Thanks.  That's what I thought, but I seem to have been unable to to see the text you quoted.